# What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google - Still Correct?

Tags: discussion

This question was asked and answered pre penguin and panda. I don't really have a problem with it's content at this point, but does it need modification two years down the line to handle issues like unnatural link penalties and the like.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google) please use the [edit](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/2/edit) feature for this community wiki Q/A to improve upon it as you see fit.

I would recommend citing sources (and preferably only those at Google) if you plan to make substantial changes to ensure that the information you add is readily understood and accepted, but aside from that I wouldn't anticipate too much discussion would need to be devoted to improvements.

Was there a particular aspect you wanted to discuss before making changes?

Comment: Mostly I wanted to see what peoples thoughts were on the need for an update. There have been substantial changes to the SEO landscape in two years, so I figured we should chat about the need.